# Display 2 category on search page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I wanna show Only 3 categories in the my page. Can anyone help
I wanna show post like this:

**post title**

category 1, category 2, category 3

**thumbnail**

*content*

I used this code

```
$category = get_the_category();
if ( $category[0] ) {
    echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '">' . $category[0]->cat_name . '</a></h2>';
}
```

but this code show me just first category, and I wanna 3 category

Comment: Looks like you'd just need to iterate over `$category` if I read documentation of `get_the_category()` right. `foreach($category as $cat) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use get_categories() instead of get_the_category(). Code should be look like:

```
$categories = get_categories();
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
   echo '<h2><a href="' . get_category_link( $categories[$i]->term_id ) . '">' . $categories[$i]->name . '</a></h2>';
}
```